# Camera coordinate appears to be left handed

Tags: camera, coordinates

It is weird that I have a camera that has a left-handed coordinate system.
All the other cameras are right handed.

Left handed camera:
[image: left handed coordinates]

Right handed camera (all others are right handed, too):
[image: all the other has right handed coordinates]

I can't tell what caused this.

Comment: Could you tell us, what you are trying to do and where the problem is?

Comment: Did you scale the camera to -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at by cegaton, you set the x-dimension of the scale to a negative value for one of the cameras. Open the properties region with <kbd>N</kbd> and set the scale back to positive 1 if you like.

[image]